# How can users upload secret images with paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Amazed at how easy paperclip makes image uploading...but sadly, the images are uploaded to the publically available `public` directory.

**How can I make my images secret, so people can't browse to them, and the only way they can see them is if they've been explicitly included with an image_tag method**? Is this easier said than done? Does `image_tag` only work with images that are publicaly available?

I just need these images to be secret and secure, and while URI obfuscation is an option, it still makes me feel a bit uneasy.

I know how to create members only areas of a site through using `http_basic_authenticate_with`, so can I use this to make the `public` directory, or certain directories of it, private?

Can't believe this functionality isn't part of the paperclip gem. I remember with apache and `.htaccess` files one way to keep an image directory secret was to ban all ip addresses from the directory except for 127.0.0.1. That did the job. Why doesn't rails allow secret images?

What options do I have for secret images? Any other image upload gems?

Comment: if you are using s3 then using signed url you can protect,it is one way you can do this

Comment: Cool, definitely bear that in mind. Seems overkill though, I only want a few dozen secret images. Thanks though.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722472/rails-paperclip-gem-get-file-from-private-folder

Comment: @BroiSatse I don't want the image to be automatically downloaded upon visiting an action, I want it appear in the view, courtesy of an `image_tag`. This only way this view can be accessed is if they're logged in, else a redirect.